# Usage of lambda in constant expression

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

Take the following code:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool can_represent(U&& w) noexcept
{
    return [] (auto&& x) {
        try {
            return T(std::forward<U>(x)) == std::forward<U>(x);
        } catch(...) {
            return false;
        }
    } (std::forward<U>(w));
}
```

I am using this function in a constant expression (template).

`gcc` compiles it without a problem. `clang` and `MSVC` don't, lamenting that the function does not result in a constant expression.

Indeed, `gcc` did not immediately accept this either; it was getting hung up on the `try`, that normally wouldn't be allowed in a `constexpr` function. That's why I had to use an immediately invoked lambda expression. However, now it works, and considering it only works with `gcc` I'm quite confused.

Which compiler is correct?
Is there a property of the lambda that permits this to work in a `constexpr` context, or is this some kind of non-standard `gcc` extension?

[I've used godbolt to compile with `clang` and `MSVC`, where as I have `gcc 8.1.0` on my machine]

Comment: simply add `constexpr` to your lambda also!

Comment: As you already compiled on godbolt, could you please add the link. That enables us to check there directly...

Comment: The [rules for what is allowed in a `constexpr` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) changed in C++20. Which version of C++ did you compile for, and which version do you want to compiler for? (If not mentioned, we're supposed to assume the current version. Is that accurate here?)

Comment: Compiles for me using the following flags: `/std:c++latest /W4`. I also had to make my comparison `operators` `constexpr`: `constexpr auto operator<=>(const Test1&) const = default;`. And lastly, I had to make the constructors of the classes I was testing `constexpr`: `constexpr Test2( Test1 ) { }`

Comment: Actually, using either `/std:c++latest` or `/std::c++20` in MSVC will compile this.

Comment: However, if any of the operations involved actually does throw, that instantiation of `can_represent` wouldn't be usable in a constant expression, even with C++20: "**[expr.const]/5** An expression `E` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `E` ... would evaluate one of the following: (5.24) — a *throw-expression* (7.6.18) or a dynamic cast (7.6.1.6) or `typeid` (7.6.1.7) expression that would throw an exception"

Comment: This should be valid if `T` can be move constructed (with or without throwing) from `U` at compile time. eg if `constexpr T(U&&)` is defined. If not, it would technically be Ill-Formed, No Diagnosis Required ("IFNDR"). Since `try catch` in `constexpr`, as mentioned by @JaMiT, was added in C++20, this would be IFNDR in prior versions of the standard, as far as I know.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to specify the C++ version. I'm using C++17.

Comment: Not related: it seems better to use SFINAE for this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [gcc] was getting hung up on the `try`, that normally wouldn't be allowed in a `constexpr` function.

This is correct for a C++17 program. (C++20 relaxed this, so a `try` block can now be used in a `constexpr` function. However, it is only the `try` that is allowed; it is not allowed for execution to hit something that throws an exception.)

> That's why I had to use an immediately invoked lambda expression.

The implication here is that your approach made your code valid. This is incorrect. Using an an immediately invoked lambda did not work around the problem; it swept the problem under the rug. The `try` is still a problem, but now compilers do not have to tell you it is a problem.

Using a lambda switches the [`constexpr` criterion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) from the straight-forward *"the function body must not contain a try-block"* to the indirect *"there exists at least one set of argument values such that an invocation of the function could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression".* The tricky part here is that a violation of the latter criterion is "no diagnostic required", meaning that all the compilers are correct, whether or not they complain about this code. Hence my characterization of this as sweeping the problem under the rug.

So why is... that criterion is a long thing to repeat... what's the issue involving "[core constant expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Core_constant_expressions)"? C++17 removed the prohibition against lambdas in core constant expressions, so that much looks good. However, there is still a requirement that all function calls within the `constexpr` function also be themselves `constexpr`. [Lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) can become `constexpr` in two ways. First, they can be explicitly marked `constexpr` (but if you do that here, the complaint about the `try` block should come back). Second, they can simply satisfy the `constexpr` function requirements. However, your lambda contains a `try`, so it is not `constexpr` (in C++17).

Your lambda is not a valid `constexpr` function. Hence calling it is not allowed in a core constant expression. There is no execution path through `can_represent()` that avoids invoking your lambda. Therefore, `can_represent` is not a valid `constexpr` function, no diagnostic required.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is there any valid way in which I can achieve what I want? That is, know at compile time if a function has thrown an exception and use that to make compile time decisions?

Comment: @super Throwing an exception is not a compile-time activity. It is not possible to throw an exception until runtime. So, yes, you can know, but that's because the answer is always "no" -- there is never a case at compile time where a function has (past tense) thrown an exception. (There might be a way to accomplish your real goal, but you did not ask about that.)